# Java array get value at index method

Tags: java, methods, get

I making a dynamic array that using normal array and mimic arraylist. So.... Please help me check if the method is correct. rangeCheck is a boolean method checking if the array is out of bound.
rangeCheck contains an outofbound exception.

```
 public int get(int position)
{
    rangeCheck(position);
    int valuePosition =0;
    for(int count=0;count == position;count++)
    {
        valuePosition = storage[count] ;
    }
    return valuePosition; 
}
```

For some idiotic reason, I keep thinking inorder to get to some value at some specific index, I have to go in a loop to do it....

Comment: Your loop doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: Why dont you use ArrayList?  ArrayList's get is O(1) and contains is O(n), thats really the best your solution can hope for so why not just use it?

Comment: dude... as I said, I using normal array and mimic array list with a growth method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
public int get(int position)
{
    boolean ok = rangeCheck(position);
    if(! ok)        
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Your error message");
    return storage[position];
}
```

Comment: Barely beat me to it, but I would add `rangeCheck(position)` before the first line of the body.

Comment: Maybe throw an exception instead of `return some_errorcode`? But yes, the idea is the same (+1).